# BigQuery: How to convert two different timestamps to the same timezone date?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two tables with timestamps by different time zones.
Like this:

```
    event_timestamp 
2021-01-18 15:20:20.731845 UTC
2021-01-18 15:20:20.731845 UTC
2021-01-18 15:20:20.731845 UTC
2021-01-18 15:20:25.773005 UTC
2021-01-18 20:54:21.878868 UTC
2021-01-18 20:54:21.878868 UTC
2021-01-18 20:54:21.878868 UTC
2021-01-18 20:54:26.868124 UTC
```

and

```
created_at  
2020-12-21 09:36:57.910823-05:00
2020-12-21 09:34:39.982893-05:00    
2020-12-21 09:38:10.960194-05:00
2020-12-21 09:38:00.316821-05:00
2020-12-21 09:38:16.776295-05:00    
2020-12-21 09:37:54.062889-05:00
2020-12-21 09:38:04.110779-05:00    
2020-12-21 09:36:07.318364-05:00
2020-12-21 09:32:05.147794-05:00
2020-12-21 09:30:42.509922-05:00
```

When I try extract dates so I get different dates

I need to make in each table column with a date by the same timezone.

This will make it possible to accurately compare data between two tables.......

It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery doesn't support timestamps in different timezones (as far as I know).  Timestamps are always UTC.

I am guessing that in the second table the column is really a string.  You can convert it to a `timestamp`:

```
select timestamp(created_at) as created_at_ts
```

Voila!  Both will be UTC.

Note:  If the first is a string, you will need to convert it as well.